# Como passar parâmetros e pegá-los com $state.go do angular?

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código no controller

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$http', '$cordovaSQLite', '$window', '$state',

function ($scope, $stateParams, $http, $cordovaSQLite, $window, $state) {

$scope.clienteId = null;
$scope.clienteNome = null;
$scope.clienteEmail = null;

$scope.profId = null;
$scope.profNome = null;
$scope.profEmail = null;

$scope.logar = function(usuario){

    $scope.error = null;
    $scope.errors = {};

    $http.post("http://vigilantescomunitarios.com/serviapp/api_gustavo/login.php", usuario).success(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        if(response == '' || response == [] || response == 'null'){
            $scope.msgErro = "E-mail ou senha inválido";
            return;

        }else if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

            var prof = response.e_profissional;
            var id = response.idusuario;
            var nome = response.nome;
            var email = response.email;

            if(prof == 1){
                $scope.profNome = nome;
                $scope.profEmail = email;
                $scope.profId = id;
                console.log($scope.profNome);

                $state.go('menuProfissional', { "nome": nome, "email": email, "id": id });
            }else{
                $scope.clienteId = id;
                $scope.clienteNome = nome;
                $scope.clienteEmail = email;
                console.log($scope.clienteNome);

                $state.go('menuCliente');
            }
        }

        })

     }

}])
```

E o controller onde vou pegar eles

```
app.controller('menuProfissionalCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'stateParams', function ($scope, $stateParams, stateParams) {

$state.params.nome;
console.log($state.params.nome);


}])
```

Porém, o que aparece no console é "NaN"

O que tenho que corrigir para pegar o nome, email e id?

Comment: Onde está definida sua rota `menuProfissional`?

Comment: .state('menuProfissional', {
    url: '/menuProfissional/:nome/:email/:id',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menuProfissional.html',
    controller: 'menuProfissionalCtrl'
  })

Comment: Para pegar o valor você só precisa usar `$stateParams.nome` dentro do seu controller. Testa pra ver se te atende

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o valor você deve usar o `service` [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) que irá conter o valor que foi passado pelo `$state.go`. Por exemplo, no `menuProfissionalCtrl`:

```
...
console.log($stateParams.nome);
...
```

**Dica:** Este [link](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) contém um manual de boas práticas que facilita a manutenção e criação de código usando o Angular 1.x.

Comment: Consegui.Obrigado.